# Memory leaks in Appcelerator Android HTTP?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am running into what looks like a memory leak on Android using Appcelerator. I am making an HTTP GET call repeatedly until all data is loaded. This call happens about 50 times, for a total of roughly 40 MB of JSON. I am seeing the memory usage spike dramatically if this is executed. If I execute these GETs the heap size (as reported by Android Device Monitor, the preferred method to check memory according to the official Appcelerator docs) gets up to ~240 MB *and stays there for as long as the app runs*. If I do not execute these GETs, it only uses about 50 MB. I don't think this is a false heap reading either, because if I execute the GETs again (from page 1) I run out of memory.

I have looked through the code and cannot find any obvious leaks, such as storing all results in a global variable or something. Are the HTTP responses being cached somewhere?

Here is my code, for reference. `syncThings(1, 20)` (sanitized name :) ) gets called during startup. It in turn calls a helper function `syncDocuments()`. Here are the two functions. Don't worry about `launchMainWindow()` unless you think it could be relevant, but assume it does no cleanup.

```
function syncThings(page, itemsPerPage) {
    var url = "the_url";

    console.log("Getting page " + page);
    syncDocuments(url,
        function(response) {
            if (response.totalDocumentsInQuery == itemsPerPage) {
                // More pages to get
                setTimeout(function() {
                        syncThings(page + 1, itemsPerPage);
                    }, 1);
            } else {
                // This was the last page
                launchMainWindow();
            }
        },
        function(e) {
            Ti.API.error('Default error callback called for syncThings;', e);
            dispatcher.trigger('app:update:stop');
        });
}


function syncDocuments(url, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    new HTTPRequest({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        timeout: 30000,
        success: function (response) {
            Ti.API.info('Success callback called for ' + url);
            successCallback(response);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            errorCallback(error);
        }
    }).send();
}
```

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong here?

Edit: I am using Titanium SDK 6.0.1.GA. This happens on all Android versions.

Comment: I tried using HTTPClient. It was more efficient, but it still eventually runs out of memory if I chain enough calls.

Comment: what are you doing with the response data? Because if you assign it to a variable and use it somewhere, of course it stays in memory. Perhaps you should write the responses to files

Comment: Did you try to run the GC in Android Monitor to free the memory and does it still retain? Perhaps there wasn't the need to free the memory in your test case?

Comment: The response data is stored into a database, then the response data falls out of scope. Several other developers have reviewed the code and don't see anywhere the variables would be stored. At any rate, for this question I'm assuming it's not happening, and asking if it's possible Appcelerator is doing something (caching HTTP responses?) to cause this.

I did try hitting the GC button in Android Monitor, and it made no difference.

Comment: To be clear, to simplify the code I posted I omitted the database writes. However, if I execute the above code (i.e. response received, then I do nothing with it) I see the same memory usage as if I wrote it to the DB. The heap size is almost identical (within 1%). Because of this, I am zeroing in on the HTTP request as the issue.

Comment: I would agree with @RenePot. I think the response reference is being retained somewhere. Try to write the response to a file and see that you are not using them to store in a global variable.

Comment: I am 95% sure it is not being retained explicitly by the code, unless inside Appcelerator or the HTTPClient. I mean, what I just posted was literally just copied from my testing code. I only renamed some things, and I didn't omit the database writes: the code I've been testing with does not even do anything with the response. Globals are not even used. It sounds like, however, that it's not expected for the responses to be cached "behind the scenes".

Answer (score 0):

Try using the file-property of the HTTPClient: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-property-file

otherwise the file will be loaded into memory.

There will be a memory leak fix in 6.1.0: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/8818 that might fix something too.